# Spring data neo4j change of database context at runtime

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am having a really hard time using `spring-data-neo4j` using neo4j 4.0.0. With this version of Neo4j, there is a possibility to switch between databases, and I need to do this to implement a multi-tenancy system where each tenant has its own database.

However, `spring-data-neo4j` doesn't seem to provide any way to switch of database at runtime with the latest version (this also have to be thread-safe).

What I thought of is to create a single `sessionFactory` per tenant doing so

```kotlin
    val sessionFactory = createTenantSessionFactory()
    val session = sessionFactory.openSession()
    val factory = Neo4jRepositoryFactory(session, mappingContext)
    val repository = factory.getRepository(DesiredNeo4jRepository::class.java)
```

However, with this solution, I am experiencing problems of concurrency, even though requests are executed one after the other in a single thread, the result in the database end up wrong.

I figured out that this might probably be because I am not using transaction management support offered by spring with this solution, because `Neo4jTransactionManager` is not created.

I realise this is really complex question, but did I take a good approach for the problem, or is there a better alternative I haven't seen?

If there is no better way, how can I support transaction management with this solution?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is a new version of Spring Data Neo4j, called SDN RX, out there. It is planned to be the successor of the classic SDN (https://github.com/neo4j/sdn-rx). We have a blog post out there how to use it with multi tenancy https://medium.com/neo4j/reactive-multi-tenancy-with-neo4j-4-0-and-sdn-rx-d8ae0754c35

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix it for now using the solution from https://community.neo4j.com/t/spring-data-neo4j-4-0-release-multi-tenant/12920

So I implemented an `TenantContext`

```kotlin
object ApplicationContext {

    private val currentTenant = ThreadLocal<String>()

    fun setCurrentTenant(tenantName: String) {
        currentTenant.set(tenantName)
    }

    fun getCurrentTenant(): String? {
        return currentTenant.get()
    }

    // Just a utility function
    fun withTenantContext(tenant: String, handler: (() -> Unit)) {
        val currentTenant = getCurrentTenant()
        setCurrentTenant(tenant)
        handler()

        if (currentTenant != null) {
            setCurrentTenant(currentTenant)
        } else {
            clearTenant()
        }
    }

    fun clearTenant() {
        currentTenant.remove()
    }
}
```

And override the session factory. Unfortunately, `SessionFactory` doesn't expose an interface, so I had to override it and pass a fake package and an empty driver (Just implement `org.neo4j.ogm.driver.Driver` class and leave it empty).

This is more a hotfix than a real solution while waiting for a solution from `spring-data-neo4j`, but it works in a multi-thread context and suits my needs.

```kotlin
class MultiTenantSessionFactory(private val sessionFactories: ConcurrentMap<String, SessionFactory>) : SessionFactory(EmptyDriver(), "fake.package") {


    override fun openSession(): Session {
        return getSessionFactory(getCurrentTenantOrThrow()).openSession()
    }

    override fun close() {
        getSessionFactory(getCurrentTenantOrThrow()).close()
    }

    private fun getSessionFactory(tenantName: String): SessionFactory {
        return sessionFactories[tenantName] ?: throw UnregisteredSessionFactoryException(tenantName)
    }

    private fun getCurrentTenantOrThrow(): String {
        return ApplicationContext.getCurrentTenant() ?: throw EmptyTenantContextException()
    }
}
```

Finally, just create a bean for this session factory while using `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(tenantRepository: TenantRepository): SessionFactory {
        return MultiTenantSessionFactory(
                tenantRepository.findAll()
                        .map { tenant -> tenant.name to initTenantSessionFactory(tenant) }
                        .toMap(ConcurrentHashMap())
        )
    }
```

You should now be able to use all your `Neo4jRepository` transparently in a multi-tenant context. Hope this helps someone!